# Why am I getting a 'No such file or directory' error when attempting to run 'rails s' in Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git

there. I am working on a project in a small team, our app is build on the ruby on rails, I am Front End Developer and do all React stuff, but recently we updated version of ruby to the latest one, rails also. And after that I can not even start an app in Git Bash with `rails s`.

I work on Windows machine, and all commands with ruby, rails works perfect in Power Shell, but in Git Bash I can not even simply check the version of rails. All the time I get this error:

```
/c/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails: line 6: /c/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Please, anybody who knows how to fix it, answer me. Thanks

I do not understand what is the problem, reinstalled ruby and git few times, but nothing works. I can start an app and work with a project from Power Shell, but it is harder for me, than just use Git Bash from VS Code

Comment: Try opening this file with Notepad++ and deleting everything that comes before the "require" line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess when you installed Ruby, you changed the Ruby's install path. You can edit it here:

```
/c/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails
```

line 6. Update to your real ruby install path

For example， when I executed the command `jekyll server`, the same problem occurred. I edit the file

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\jekyll
```

from

```
exec "${binpath}/ruby" "-x" "$0" "$@"
```

to

```
exec "D:/Program/develop/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby" "-x" "$0" "$@"
```

Answer (score -1):

Clean Installation of Ruby resolved the problem:

--Uninstall the Ruby

--Manually delete Ruby folder from C:\Ruby.x...

--OPTIONAL: Restart the system as it will remove the temp folder which may hinder the reinstallation of Ruby

--Reinstall Ruby

Enjoy :))